# Struct member array; creation and access through use of return pointer type function

Tags: c

### Preface.

This is my first question here, so sorry if it doesn't conform to a standard format or way of phrasing a question etc.
I'm not ignorant to the fact that this probably has been answered somewhere in the depths, but I've searched through the best of my ability and I couldn't find anything that was similar enough in such a way that it helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

I'm fairly new at C, have programming experience but I do lack large chunks of fundamentals. Which will show through my attempts at explaining and describing the problem.  I appreciate the feedback, but I honestly have a very low aptitude for understanding computer science definitions, so would appreciate applied examples as opposed to a quote. Thanks in advance for the extra trouble!

---

Ok, so for the actual problem;

I am trying to create a list without using list() at all, so far I've gotten to the point where I want to confirm I'm actually doing it.

- Create a function that returns a struct with the list/array of whatever length I want it to be.
- Check that the function does what I want it to do by seeing if the content of the struct member elements is the content of arraytest..

header includes the following

```
//header 

typedef struct {
    size_t length;
    int elements[];
}list_t;

list_t *new_list(size_t length, int elements[]);
```

Source file so far (forego include/defines because it really isn't relevant here)

```
list_t *new_list(size_t length, int elements[])
{
    list_t* newList = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(list_t*) + sizeof(int) * length);
    
    newList->length = length;
    newList->elements[length - 1];

    return newList;
}


int main()
{
    int arraytest[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    int length      = 6;
    
    list_t* list = new_list(length, arraytest);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("The address of [%d] element : %p\n", i, &list->elements[i]);
        printf("The value of [%d] element : %u\n", i, list->elements[i]);
        printf("The pointer value of [%d] element : %p\n", i, list->elements[i]);
        printf("No [] index iteration of [%d] element : %p\n", i, list->elements);
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen from the main, I have tried to mentally grasp at different things that I have thought may be the cause for my ?confusion? on this..

I'm obviously trying to confirm that I actually have my array by printing the elements, accessible by index.
Normally, I've done this in structs before but always with a predefined size and never through a function pointer return (or with a array parameter for that matter). Its for the most part gone ok, and I've not had any issues.

However, I guess what I'm trying to get at here is WHAT am I essentially missing?

I thought of a few things;

1. Either I'm missing the fact that C uses pass by value and that somehow the function return pointer isn't being treated as such, either in the main or by the function new_list itself, I don't really know.
2. The syntax I'm using is not the correct one for the confirmation I'm trying to get, I already have what I want and I'm missing something extremely trivial.
3. The function *new_list is wrong and I'm not returning a what I think I'm returning.
4. Any combination of the above and probably something else, or something else entirely.

I have tried from the prints to see whether or not its a dereferencing thing, but since I'm already using arrays I've honestly just tried to throw in a few different things since I feel the distinction with respect to arrays and pointers are not 100% clear.

For example I know, or rather I think I know the distinction between using * as a pointer vs a dereferencing operator, get address of & and -> is used for struct member access and so on, that's clear to me I suppose. But I cant say I honestly get it once you throw in arrays in the mix.

Regardless, I'm gonna stop there, I think this gets the point across (++).

oh and the program executes and runs, I don't get any errors, only some compiler warnings about formatting, which shouldn't really be the issue I think.

Again, thanks for the help !

Comment: As a statement, `newList->elements[length - 1];` does nothing useful. It fetches the value from element `length - 1` of the array, and then discard that value.

Comment: Also note that you never initialize the array and its elements. All elements in the array will have *indeterminate* values.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(list_t*) + ...` --> `malloc(sizeof(list_t) + ...` You don't want the `sizeof` a pointer.

Comment: Yes you have a flexible array member, and the `malloc` call (once fixed as mentioned by @DavidRanieri above) will allocate memory for the array. ***But*** it will *not* initialize the allocated memory in any way. `malloc` itself only allocates memory, it doesn't initialize the memory. And there's no code shown that does it either. You never set the memory to any value, you never assign to any of the elements.

Comment: Deleting previous comment; I saw what you meant..

Comment: You pass an array of 5 integers to the `new_list()` function but tell it that the length is (should be) 6.  That makes it hard to know what should be copied.  You will need to sort that out before you add a loop to the function to copy the data into the structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
Ok, I'll bite on the obvious big hole I'm missing and fill in further ignorance:

I thought I was doing exactly that when I was declaring/defining the arraytest and calling the function new_list with arraytest as a parameter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
I wanted to make sure it had enough space for the null terminator is why I have the extra length.  Guess that was wrong too.

Comment: Right, so if I get it correctly..  What I'm doing with the function parameter is I'm initializing the size of the array, but the array itself is not put into the member array at all. 
I did a list->elements[0] = 4; as a separate statement and that worked fine..  
I don't know why, but I for some reason thought it would work with an array as a parameter directly..   back to the drawing board I suppose.

Comment: Null terminators apply to strings (array of `char`), not to other types.  Sometimes, zero is used as a sentinel to mark the end of the data in another array type.  But it would be an unusual interface that specifies 6 where five values are supplied/copied and a zero should be added.  It can be done.  But my gut feel is it will invite bugs.

Comment: You can't sensibly terminate an array of `int` with a sentinel value unless you know for sure of one which will never be present in the data. And besides there is no point in doing that when the size is known in advance as in this case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was not aware of that fact, I thought null term was a feature of all arrays, thanks a lot for pointing it out! I shan't forget that.

Comment: @Lundin As you've read by now probably I was unaware of "\0" being exclusive to char arrays.  sorry about that.

Comment: It's not exclusive to char arrays - it is exclusive to char arrays _used as strings_.

Comment: Be aware that even though all strings are null-terminated character arrays, you can have character arrays that are not strings.  Those often cause bugs when they are (mis)treated as strings.

Comment: Ok, assimilating that important detail.  Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1):

- `list_t* newList = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(list_t*) + sizeof(int) * length);` is wrong, should be `sizeof(list_t) + ...`.
- `newList->elements[length - 1];` is a no-op, it has no side effects and the compiler should tell you as much. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) You probably meant to set the item to zero.
- Ideally check if malloc didn't succeed and returned NULL.
- `new_list(length, arraytest);` You lie to the function and say that you pass 6 items when you only pass 5.
- `printf("The pointer value of [%d] element : %p\n", i, list->elements[i]);` doesn't make sense, this isn't a pointer. As already established in your first printf line, you'd have to write `&list->elements[i]` to get an address. Same problem in several printf statements.
- `free()` all dynamically allocated items when you are done using them.

Comment: Not enough comment space for the feedback I was writing, but yea. Thanks for the details ! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I would use `realloc` to make the function more universal.
@Lundin made a nice list of errors in your code so I will not repeat it in this answer

```
typedef struct {
    size_t length;
    int elements[];
}list_t;

list_t *addToList(list_t *list, size_t length, const int *elements)
{
    size_t newLength = list ? list -> length + length : length;

    list = realloc(list, sizeof(*list) + newLength * sizeof(list -> elements[0]));
    if(list)
    {
        size_t startPos = newLength == length ? 0 : list -> length;
        for(size_t pos = startPos; pos < newLength; pos++)
        {
            list -> elements[pos] = *elements++;
        }
        list -> length = newLength;
    }
    return list;
} 


int main(void)
{
    int arraytest[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    size_t length = sizeof(arraytest) / sizeof(arraytest[0]);
    
    list_t* list = NULL; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        list_t *tmp = addToList(list, length, arraytest);
        if(tmp)
        {
            list = tmp;
            printf("List length %zu\n Elements:", list -> length);
            for(size_t pos = 0; pos < list -> length; pos++)
                printf("%d ", list -> elements[pos]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        for(size_t pos = 0; pos < length; pos++) arraytest[pos] = arraytest[length - 1] + pos + 1;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/P3rdPjM6o

Comment: I'd change `*elements++` to `elements[pos]`.

Comment: @Lundin It would not work as `pos` is not <zero; elements.length) (except the first call).  More maths would me needed